# How come my loop is not displaying properly in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm64, armv8

```
.output: .string "X = %d, Y = %d Current Minimum of Y is:%d \n"
.balign 4
.global main

main:   stp     x29, x30, [sp,-16]!
        mov     x29, sp
        mov     x18, -10        // The variable X
        mov     x19, 0          // The variable Y
        mov     x20, 0          // Current minimum of Y

Loop:
        cmp     x18, 4           // Compare X (x18) with 4
        b.gt    end

        mov     x19, 0          // Set Y to zero for each loop
        mov     x21, 0          // x21, x22, and x23 initialize variables for the equation
        mov     x22, 0
        mov     x23, 0

        add     x19, x19, -127  // Y - 127

        mov     x24, -15         // Load immediate value -15 into x24
        mul     x24, x24, x18   // X becomes -15x, store the result in x24
        add     x21, x19, x24   // Y = -15x - 127

        mov     x24, x18         // Load immediate value x into x24
        mul     x24, x24, x24   // x24 becomes x^2
        mov     x25, 31          // Load immediate value 31 into x25
        mul     x24, x24, x25   // x^2 becomes 31x^2
        add     x22, x21, x24   // Y = 31x^2 - 15x - 127

        mov     x24, x18         // Load immediate value x into x24
        mul     x24, x24, x24   // x24 becomes x^2
        mul     x24, x24, x18   // x^2 becomes x^3
        mov     x25, 3           // Load immediate value 3 into x25
        mul     x24, x24, x25   // x^3 becomes 3x^3
        add     x23, x24, x22   // Y = 3x^3 + 31x^2 - 15x - 127

        cmp     x23, x20
        b.lt    update_min

        b       print

update_min:
        mov     x20, x23

print:  adrp    x0, .output
        add     x0, x0, :lo12: .output
        mov     x1, x18
        mov     x2, x23
        mov     x3, x20
        bl      printf

        add     x18, x18, 1       // Increment X (x18)
        b       Loop

end:    ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 16
       ret
```

I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of assembly and my first major chunk of code is to have an equation loop over values from -10 to 4 and display the current minimum Y.

For some reason the Minimum Y value shows up as 0 from -10 to -2 and then works properly.

I think this has something to do with the fact that I set the Y register to 0 for each loop to prevent the previous result from carrying over. To that end I've tried to edit that line so its and very small number, but that didn't work. I also tried to edit the `update_min` label so it adds zero instead of moving the current value to it in case its smaller.

From here, I don't actually know what needs to be changed here. Can some help point me into the right direction?

Comment: If some of the early Y values are greater than zero, they'll be ignored because you set the initial min to 0, not LONG_MAX (`mov x20, 1<<63 - 1`, which yes AArch64 can do in one 4-byte instruction, with bit-range immediates.)  When you single-step with a debugger, are the desired Y values present in a register?

Comment: The correct Y is displayed, but the current minimum shows 0 instead of 123.

Comment: `0` is less than `123`, so your logic for updating `cur_min = min(cur_min, y)` appears to be working correctly, given the initializer you chose.

Comment: The issue is that Y =123 is supposed to be the first minimum. I only set Y = 0 so I wouldn't get numbers like -137874. If the logic says 0 is there a way to fix that for the first couple?

Comment: `madd` can replace your `mul` and `add` to save an instruction, e.g. `madd  x21, x24, x18, x19` and there are a couple of occurrences where that can be employed (won't fix your logic, just a tip) In response to your last comment, what I generally do is use a register as a flag to determine if the max/min values have been set yet. If they haven't, you set the max/min to the first values seen and clear the flag so they are not initialized again. That way you never have a question whether your initial value creates a range problem in sensing a new max/min.

Comment: I know, I'm not using it on purpose.

Comment: @DreamCloud: Yes, you don't have to think in assembly to get the logic right.  Like in C or any language, start with `cur_min = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`, the largest possible value, so whatever the first real value is, `cur_min = min(cur_min, y)` will update it to the correct value.  Or peel the first iteration and set `cur_min` with that first value.  Or I guess you could introduce more state like David suggests and have a separate flag to say whether it's been set yet.

Comment: I have a bignum error when I implement the change.

Comment: If you don't like `movz` and `movk` you can always use negation on a register initialized zero to set all bits `1` and then add or subtract as needed for the signed min you want. What's wrong with the macros?

Comment: I had one too many `F`s in my constant, that's why the assembler complains about a bignum.  `mov x20, (1<<63) - 1` correctly sets it to LONG_MAX, like `mov  x20, 0x7fffffffffffffff`.  (@DavidC.Rankin - `mov x20, -1` would set it to all-ones = ULONG_MAX, but you don't want that.  They're doing signed comparison with `b.lt`, and that bit-pattern represents `-1` as a signed integer.  AArch64 can encode `mov reg, -1` in a single instruction as `movn`, move-not with an immediate 0)

Comment: Glad you got it working. While I miss the convenience of the condition codes on the instructions from 32-bit arm, after working with aarch64 for a while, it is a pretty darn slick instruction set. Good luck with your coding! (aside... using `fp` and `lr` is a lot more readable than `x29` and `x30`.... at least for the old guys...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: AArch64 can't predicate every non-SIMD/FP instruction like ARM could, but it has better instructions for branchless scalar code than any other ISA I know of (except maybe x86's upcoming APX which adds conditional load/store and fixes `setcc`'s warts).  `csinc` and `csel` combined with the zero-register allow everything x86's `setcc` and `cmovcc` can do and more, or conditional increment of other registers.  The OP's use-case doesn't need a branch, just a `csel` (conditional-select)

Comment: Yep, I really like the condition increment and select. The conditional branch is nice too. The big miss for functions from 32-bit is the loss of `stm` and `ldm` for prologue and epilogue use -- `stp`, `ldp` are just too (two) limited.... That said, there is a lot to like in aarch64 itself. In addition to the conditional select/increment, the `madd`, `msub` type combinations are excellent. I'm still peeling back layers of the aarch64 onion, but each time "I wish I could..." if I look hard enough, I usually find the developers thought of that too.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Didn't see your reply right away without the @ notification.  `stm` / `ldm` are very non-RISC, a variable number of loads and stores from one instruction so 32-bit ARM CPUs had to decode it to multiple uops.  I'm not surprised AArch64 dropped that, keeping just features that pipeline easily.  I thought 32-bit mode had `madd` and `msub`, for doing remainders.  https://godbolt.org/z/9xoz81vxb - yeah, `c - a*b` compiles to `mls` for ARMv6 at least.  But yeah, madd and msub would be nice to have on other ISAs.  AArch64 repeating-bit-pattern immediates for booleans are also amazing.